# JTATransactionManager Reports Successful Commit but no records in database

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, entitymanager

I'm running into a strange issue where my entity manager isn't committing to the database. I've checked my logs and no errors are found and queries seem to be executing just fine.The debugging statements from the JPATransactionManager suggest that it is calling the method and attempting to merge/persist but there are no hibernate insert statements being displayed in my log.

Using Jboss 6.1.0 nd Spring 3.1.1

web.xml:

```
 ` <web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    metadata-complete="true">
    <display-name>spring-intel</display-name>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath*:META-INF/spring/applicationContext*.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>IntelWsClient</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.ijet.service.intel.IntelWsDriver</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>IntelWsClient</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/IntelWsClient</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>


</web-app>
```

applicationContext.xml:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.pwo.dao" />
<context:annotation-config/>
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager"/>
<bean  class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />


<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="myPU" />

</bean>


<bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager">
    <property name="transactionManagerName" value="java:TransactionManager"/>
    <property name="userTransactionName" value="UserTransaction"/>
</bean>


</beans>
```

Repository Class:

```
@Service("myService")
public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService {

@PersistenceContext
EntityManager em;

public void setEntityManager(EntityManager em) {
    this.em = em;
}


@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.SUPPORTS)
public Item findItem(Integer itemId) {
    return em.find(Item.class, itemId);
}

@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public void storeItem(Item item) {
    if (item != null && item.getId() != null) {
        em.merge(item);
    } else
        em.persist(item);

    em.flush();
}
}
```

persistence.xml

```
  <persistence-unit name="myPU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
<jta-data-source>java:pwo-DS</jta-data-source>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
 <properties> 
  <property name="hibernate.validator.autoregister_listeners" value="false"/>
  <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect"/>  
  <!--property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="false"/-->
  <property name='hibernate.cache.provider_class' value='org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider'/>
  <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
   <property name="hibernate.order_inserts" value="true"/>
    <property name="hibernate.order_updates" value="true"/>
    <property name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class" value="org.hibernate.transaction.JBossTransactionManagerLookup"/>
</properties>
```

Comment: If you're running inside JBoss, with a persistence context handled by JBoss, my guess is that you should you use a JTA transaction manager, instead of a JpaTransactionManager (which is typically used outside of an application server, when JTA isn't available, and the EM uses RESOURCE_LOCAL.

Comment: I'll try switching my application over to use use JTA and let you know what happens. :)

Comment: @JBNizet I've switched my application over to use a JTA transaction manager however I'm still having the same issue. The entitymanager is able to perform find and createNative queries however no insert statements are being generated during merge/persist/flush. Still confirmed by no records appearing in the database.